# Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function - React

Tags: reactjs

Code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">React not rendered..</div>

<script type="text/babel">

  class Circle extends React.Component() {
    render() {
      return (<h2>This is a Circle</h2>);
    }
  }

  class Square extends React.Component() {
    render() {
      return (<h2>This is a Square</h2>);
    }
  }

  class Rectangle extends React.Component() {
    render() {
      return (<h2>This is a Rectangle</h2>);
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <Circle/>
      <Square/>
      <Rectangle/>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("app"));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Error in console:
[image]

Searching for existing questions, I have verified that:

1. I am using capital "C" and not "c" in React.Component
2. I am using the latest version of React, ReactDOM and Babel.

Any pointers on what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Circle extends React.Component
class Square extends React.Component
class Rectangle extends React.Component
```

without the parenthesis will do the trick

Comment: That worked. There wasn't supposed to be a () after Component. Thank you.